# How to pass data from Node Server to Angular Service?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm able to send data from Node Server to Angular when I make an HTTP request.

How do I receive data in Angular without making an explicit request to Node server?

The functionality I want to implement in Angular is, I need to show Snackbars on top without any user interaction with the front end controls.

Which concept in Angular and Node should I use to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is WebSockets most likely. Recommend to look at [socket.io](https://socket.io/) library very easy implementation for node.js

So the ideea is that you can open a persistent connection client<->server and just can send messages bidirectionally from client to server and server to client.

Comment: Could you suggest a good article which has used `socket.io` in MEAN stack

Comment: https://medium.com/@parthkamaria/building-a-chat-app-with-mean-stack-and-socket-io-c73b012b9fc9 This one can be a good starter.